# How to test Apple redeem code feature in an iOS application?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storekit

In our ios application we are developing a redeem code feature for our in app purchases, that allows users to redeem in app purchase offer codes. I'm able to successfully redeem codes in the App Store, but I'm not able to redeem codes in my application. I'm using the following code to redeem codes:

```
SKPaymentQueue.default().presentCodeRedemptionSheet()
```

The code above will display the iOS redeem code screen. However, when I enter the redeem code, I do not receive any success response; instead, I encounter the following error.

[image]

can someone please provide guidance on the proper steps for testing the redeem code feature before going live? I am unable to find any relevant documentation on this matter.